# How do I force an command line argument string to be quoted

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have a program which should cause 2 files to be compared using `FileMerge`.

This does work, but occasionally fails. I suspect this is when the paths passed as arguments contain space characters.

The following code fragment constructs the task and launches it.

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];      //The magic line that keeps your log where it belongs
    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:PREF_COMPARE_COMMAND],
                          @"Compare",   // $0 place holder
                          source,
                          target,
                          nil];
    [task setArguments:arguments];
    [task setEnvironment:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin" forKey:@"PATH"]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pipeReadCompletionNotification:)
                                                 name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification
                                               object:file];
    [file readInBackgroundAndNotify];
    [task launch];
```

I have tried many options to try and escape spaces or enclose the paths in quotes, without success. I would welcome any suggestions.

A typical arguments as a result of a run is:-

```
"-c",
"opendiff $1 $2",
Compare,
"/Users/ian/temp/Indian Pacific/RailRes Travel Documentation1.pdf",
"/Users/ian/temp/Indian Pacific/RailRes Travel Documentation.pdf"
```

I have tried

```
[source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\\ "],
[source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\ "],
```

The 1st actually inserts `\\` the second produces a compile error `unknown escape sequence`

I tried Ken Thomases's suggestion (knowing my names don't have`'`)

```
[[@"'" stringByAppendingString:source] stringByAppendingString:@"'"],
[[@"'" stringByAppendingString:target] stringByAppendingString:@"'"],
```

Unfortunately this resulted in arguments

```
"-c",
"opendiff $1 $2",
Compare,
"'/Users/ian/temp/Indian Pacific/RailRes Travel Documentation1.pdf'",
"'/Users/ian/temp/Indian Pacific/RailRes Travel Documentation.pdf'"
```

and failed in the same way. `/Users/ian/temp/Indian does not exist`

Edit _______________________ Working Code _____________________________________

```
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"-c" ,
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ '%@' '%@'", @"opendiff", source, target],
                      nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing " " with "\ "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option to the shell takes a *single string* as argument, not multiple arguments. Create the complete shell command line as an `NSString` using `stringWithFormat`. In that string you should escape the file names just as you would in the terminal, e.g. surround them with single quotes. Pass this string as the argument after `@"-c"`.

HTH

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem. I have pasted the Working Code fragment into my question. I want to do some more testing, and need to make some other changes to my code to make it work with saved preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of special characters that the shell interprets. Using double quotes is not sufficient to make a string safe against that. You could try escaping all of the special characters, but that can be finicky.

The easiest, safest approach is to use single quotes. Those tell the shell to treat *everything* up to the next single quote verbatim with no interpretation. The only thing you need to take care about is if your string contains single quotes themselves. So, the following two lines will sanitize your `source` argument:

```
NSString* quoted_source = [source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"'\\''"];
quoted_source = [[@"'" stringByAppendingString:quoted_source] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
```

The first line turns any embedded single quote into an end single quote (we'll get to the beginning one in a moment), an escaped single quote to take the place of the one we're replacing, followed by a new open single quote. The second line wraps the whole thing with an opening single quote at the beginning and an ending one at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this didn't seem to improve matters.